# Как через роутер распределить скорость трафика?

Tags: роутер

У меня стоит роутер DIR-615. Я подключил на него 5 компов. 2 на VI_FI и 3 на шнурах. Как через роутер распределить скорость трафика на каждый отдельный комп?

Comment: У меня dir-300, на нем шнурком 1 комп подключен и 4 устройства по WiFi. Никаких тормозов не замечал. Скорость инета может мала у вас?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, но сможете включить QOS и он расставит приоритеты траффика по портам или прошивайте dd-wrt

Answer (score 1):

Прошивка DD-WRT спасет отца русской демократии. Шейперы пишутся в скриптах. Есть возможность резать скорость по mac адресу.

Comment: skykub, прекрасно работает прошивка на dlink. Я прошивал роутер, все стало без проблем, шейпит отлично по mac-адресам.

Answer (score 1):

Не советую возится. Из штатных возможностей у него только

```
Расширенные функции межсетевого экрана    NAT (Network Access Translation)    Фильтрация MAC/IP - адресов (управление доступом пользователей)    Предотвращение атак DoS    SPI (Stateful Packet Inspection)    VPN Pass-through / Multi-sessions PPTP / L2TP / IPSec    Поддержка одной DMZ
```

Это устройство для таких функций не предназначено. Считать не будет, даже с левыми прошивками, управлять теоретически может, но кривовато.